# Show that $4^\frac{1}{3}$ is an algebraic number?

Tags: irrational-numbers

How do you show that  $4^\frac{1}{3}$ is an algebraic number?

I don't understand the question nor how to begin on describing the proof to show what the question is asking.

Comment: By definition a number is algebraic if it is the root of a finite polynomial in one variable. Hence you need show $4^{1/3}$ is the root of such a polynomial. Hmm, I wonder what such a polynomial might be ....

Answer (score 3):

Is it a solution to $x^{3}-4=0$. A number is said to be algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$ if it satisfies a polynomial in one variable over $\mathbf{Q}$, equivalently over $\mathbf{Z}$, by multiplying everything by the lcm of the denominators.

Comment: But don't you think that if the OP understood the question (and they mention they do not), they would be able to come up with the solution?

Comment: True, thanks for your point. I edited it.